# Beautiful Soup: How to get timestamp inside td

Tags: beautifulsoup

How do I get the value from 'data-timestamp' and convert it into an integer using BeautifulSoup. I'm iterating through each row on a website (which is a tr class).

So if i were to set up the code as

```
ratings = []
rows = soup.select('tbody tr')
for row in rows:
'insert code here'
ratings.append(rating)
```

However, I can't seem to access the value in the data-timestamp. I've tried using attrs but I'm assuming I'm doing it wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

````
<td data-timestamp="4.5833333333333" class="hide-on-hover fill-space relative">
              <div class="col border-box text-center nowrap row large-up-text-right padding-horz-small push">```
````

Answer (score 0):

Access the tag using `[]`, then round it to two decimal points, for example:

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<td data-timestamp="4.5833333333333" class="hide-on-hover fill-space relative">
              <div class="col border-box text-center nowrap row large-up-text-right padding-horz-small push">```"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

ratings = []
rows = soup.select('td')
for row in rows:
   ratings.append(round(float(soup.select_one('td')['data-timestamp']), 2))

print(*ratings)
````

Outputs:

```
4.58
```

Comment: Hi @Mendel G thanks I will. I just tried out the exact same code that you used and I received a KeyError: 'data-timestamp'. Any thoughts on why this is occuring? Have I not installed a specific package?

Comment: @ZacharyWyman If you look at my code I changed selector for `rows`.  `rows = soup.select_one('td')`. But in your code it's `rows = soup.select('tbody tr')`. notice also the `select_*one*` Check the correct selectors. let me know

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the string value:

```
[...]
for row in rows:
  data_timestamp_str = row.find("td")['data-timestamp']
[...]
```

You can convert the string to an integer with `int(data_timestamp_str)`, but note that in your example data this wouldn't work, because the value of `data-timestamp` is 4.583333333333, which is not an integer.

Comment: I'm actually getting an error when I run this. It gives me a KeyError: 'data-timestamp'. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ZacharyWyman you should debug what is in each of your "row" elements. It might be that you need to fix first the selectors for your rows, so that they actually contain the `td` elements you then need to select. Hard to debug this for you without having the entire document you are parsing, or your code.